# How correctly use :path_names in rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-routing

I'm writing rails application and I need to change some of URL pathes of my application. But I don't want to broke my tests and make changes in view, js or controllers...

Here is my routes:

```
  resources :posts, path: 'news' do
    member do
      get  'edit/page/:page', as: :edit,    action: :edit
      post '/approve',        as: :approve, action: :approve
      post '/reject',         as: :reject,  action: :reject
    end

    collection do
      get :my
      get :shared_with_me
      get :filtered
    end
  end
```

As you see I found a way to change `domain.com/posts` to `domain.com/news` in all website's pathes.

Now I need do change this list of pathes:

- from `domain.com/news` to `domain.com/news/all` (get `posts#index`)
- from `domain.com/news/12` to `domain.com/news/preview/12` (get `posts#show`)
- from `domain.com/news/new` to `domain.com/news/request` (get `posts#new`)

I'm trying to change this pathes using `:path_names`, but it doesn't working...

Here is updated routes:

```
  resources :posts, path: 'news', path_names: {index: 'all', show: 'preview', new: 'request'} do
    member do
      get  'edit/page/:page', as: :edit,    action: :edit
      post '/approve',        as: :approve, action: :approve
      post '/reject',         as: :reject,  action: :reject
    end

    collection do
      get :my
      get :shared_with_me
      get :filtered
    end
  end
```

When I made this changes and runs `rake routes` - only `GET news/request` appears..

But why I don't see `GET news/all` and `GET news/:id/review` ?

Please, help me to fix it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the controller to use for a resource instead of using the `path` hack:

```
resources :news, controller: 'posts' do

end
```

When it comes to the rest of you question maybe you should learn the hows and why's of the RESTful defaults instead.

Using `/news/all` is pretty idiosyncratic - in REST its implied if a path describes a resource than the "root" should display all items.

```
get 'edit/page/:page'
```

Is just plain weird. If page is a nested resource of `news` you would declare it like so:

```
resources :news, controller: 'posts' do
   resources :pages
   # or
   resource :page
end
```

You also should not be using the POST verb to approve / reject a story. POST implies that you are creating a resource. Instead you might want to do something like:

```
resources :news, controller: 'posts' do
   member do
     patch :approve
     patch :reject
   end
end
```

Yes this will break you tests - waah waah. However building bad applications just to avoid changing existing code / tests is not a viable long term approach.